# Integrated terminal disappeared in idea 2018

Tags: intellij-idea

I have installed intellij idea 2018.1. I can't open integrated terminal shell. It's useful window for me.

There is no button in left drop-up menu. There are: Event Logs, Favorites, Project, but no terminal :(

Comment: Make sure the Terminal bundled plugin is enabled in [plugins settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/enabling-and-disabling-plugins.html) To open it use View | Tool Windows | Terminal.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Terminal is a plugin. See the plugin section to enable it.

Comment: Go to Preferences > Plugins, click on "Installed" tab & Enable Terminal plugin

Comment: Preferences > Plugins > search Terminal and enable it